# How to round number from json in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want to round the number because it has too many decimal

This is the screenshot:

[image]

This is my JSON response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "NoSPTA": "096342",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0HG0",
      "namaptn": "MUNIP  KHUSAINI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017  14:55:33",
      "TglBruto": null,
      "TglGiling": null,
      "TglTara": null,
      "Netto": "0.0",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "096341",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0HG0",
      "namaptn": "MUNIP  KHUSAINI",
      "TglGawang": null,
      "TglBruto": null,
      "TglGiling": null,
      "TglTara": null,
      "Netto": "0.0",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "096322",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0S90",
      "namaptn": "LIANI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017  19:36:21",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017 23:02:06",
      "TglGiling": "09\/08\/2017  00:56:13",
      "TglTara": "09\/08\/2017  00:56:13",
      "Netto": "75.201000000000008",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "096321",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0NV0",
      "namaptn": "LIANI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017  17:18:46",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017 18:38:12",
      "TglGiling": "08\/08\/2017  21:05:43",
      "TglTara": "08\/08\/2017  21:05:43",
      "Netto": "74.001000000000005",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095878",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0Q80",
      "namaptn": "LIANI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017  10:36:05",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017 10:38:14",
      "TglGiling": "08\/08\/2017  12:33:00",
      "TglTara": "08\/08\/2017  12:33:00",
      "Netto": "75.001000000000005",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095877",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0Q80",
      "namaptn": "LIANI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017  10:36:40",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017 10:59:59",
      "TglGiling": "08\/08\/2017  13:04:49",
      "TglTara": "08\/08\/2017  13:04:49",
      "Netto": "90.40100000000001",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095788",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZP0N50",
      "namaptn": "YUDI  HERMANTO",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017 15:30:51",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017  14:54:55",
      "TglGiling": "08\/08\/2017 16:59:39",
      "TglTara": "08\/08\/2017  16:59:39",
      "Netto": "65.600999999999999",
      "RF": "D",
      "Potongan": "5.0000000000000003E-2"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095787",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZP0N50",
      "namaptn": "YUDI  HERMANTO",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017 15:02:24",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017  14:34:53",
      "TglGiling": "08\/08\/2017 16:23:57",
      "TglTara": "08\/08\/2017  16:23:57",
      "Netto": "40.501000000000005",
      "RF": "D",
      "Potongan": "5.0000000000000003E-2"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095786",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZP0N50",
      "namaptn": "YUDI  HERMANTO",
      "TglGawang": null,
      "TglBruto": null,
      "TglGiling": null,
      "TglTara": null,
      "Netto": "0.0",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095785",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZP0N50",
      "namaptn": "YUDI  HERMANTO",
      "TglGawang": null,
      "TglBruto": null,
      "TglGiling": null,
      "TglTara": null,
      "Netto": "0.0",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095784",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZP0N50",
      "namaptn": "YUDI  HERMANTO",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017 22:21:55",
      "TglBruto": "09\/08\/2017  00:43:30",
      "TglGiling": "09\/08\/2017 02:36:22",
      "TglTara": "09\/08\/2017  02:36:22",
      "Netto": "58.200999999999993",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095583",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0Q90",
      "namaptn": "LIANI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017  20:18:50",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017 23:46:57",
      "TglGiling": "09\/08\/2017  01:46:32",
      "TglTara": "09\/08\/2017  01:46:32",
      "Netto": "77.900999999999996",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "NoSPTA": "095582",
      "TglBerlakuSPTA": "2017-08-07  23:59:59.000",
      "Kdptn": "IA045ZN0HG0",
      "namaptn": "MUNIP  KHUSAINI",
      "TglGawang": "07\/08\/2017 07:37:47",
      "TglBruto": "08\/08\/2017  04:05:11",
      "TglGiling": "08\/08\/2017 08:26:31",
      "TglTara": "08\/08\/2017  08:26:31",
      "Netto": "93.90100000000001",
      "RF": "",
      "Potongan": "0.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my index.php

```
<?php
    // include "database.php";
    include "db.php";
    $obj->tglan=$obj->get_hari();
    if (isset($_POST['tanggal2'])) {
        $obj->tglan = $_POST['tanggal2'];

    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/DataTables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <center>

        <h3>Daftar SPTA<br><?php echo $obj->tanggal("D, j M Y",$obj->tglan);?></h3>
    </center>
    <left>
        <h5>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspLast refreshed : <?php echo $obj->tanggal("D, j M Y",$obj->tglan)." ".date("H:i:s");?></h5>
    </left>
    <br/>
    <form action="viewLaporanUtama2.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="tanggal">&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTanggal</label>
                <input type="text" name="tanggal1" class="tanggal" id="myText" required/>
                <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Cari" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            </div>
     </form>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table border = '0' class="table table-striped table-bordered data" id="tabelSpta">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th>No</th> -->
                    <th>No SPTA</th>            
                    <th>No Register Induk</th>
                    <th>Nama Petani</th>
                    <th>Gawang/Pos</th>
                    <th>Timbang Bruto</th>
                    <th>Giling</th>
                    <th>Timbang Tarra</th>
                    <th>Netto(kw)</th>
                    <th>Kode Rafraksi</th>
                    <th>Potongan (kw)</th>
                    <th>Netto Akhir (kw)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th>No</th> -->
                    <th>No SPTA</th>            
                    <th>No Register Induk</th>
                    <th>Nama Petani</th>
                    <th>Gawang/Pos</th>
                    <th>Timbang Bruto</th>
                    <th>Giling</th>
                    <th>Timbang Tarra</th>
                    <th>Netto(kw)</th>
                    <th>Kode Rafraksi</th>
                    <th>Potongan (kw)</th>
                    <th>Netto Akhir (kw)</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <<!-- tbody>
                <div id="bagReload">
                    <?php
                        // echo $obj->tampilLaporan();
                    ?>
                </div>

            </tbody> -->
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var tabel = $('#tabelSpta').DataTable({
        "deferRender": false,
                    "footerCallback": function (tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api();
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
            var p = api.column(10).data().reduce(function (c, d) { //Mengatur penjumlahan total akhir di kolom ke-4 (Kolom Total)
                return parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d);
            }, 0)
            $(api.column(10).footer()).html(p); //Mengatur letak hasil total dari var p (Diletakan di footer kolem ke-4) nb:Kolom mulai dar index ke-0
            // $("#total").val(p);
        },
                    "ajax": "database.php",
                    "order": [[ 3, 'asc' ]],
                    "columns": [
                        { 
                            "data": "NoSPTA",
                            "width": "120px",
                            "sClass": "text-center"
                        },
                        { "data": "Kdptn" },
                        { "data": "namaptn" },
                        { "data": "TglGawang" },
                        { "data": "TglBruto" },
                        { "data": "TglGiling" },
                        { "data": "TglTara" },
                        { "data": "Netto" },
                        { "data": "RF" },
                        { "data": "Potongan" },
                        { "data": "Netto" },
                    ],  
        });

    });

</script>
<!-- <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.tanggal').datepicker({
                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                    autoclose:true
                });
            });
</script>
</html>
```

And this is my database.php

```
<?php

    $serverName="192.168.1.250";
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName; Database=tebu", "sa", "sukseskan");

    $query = "SELECT   a.spa AS NoSPTA,
                        a.tglberlaku as TglBerlakuSPTA, 
                        a.Kdptn, 
                        a.namaptn, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,b.tgl,103)+' '+ convert(           varchar,b.tgl,108)) 
                        AS TglGawang, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,c.tgl,103)+' '+ convert(varchar,c.tgl,108)) 
                        AS TglBruto, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,c.tglgil,103)+' '+ convert(varchar,c.tglgil,108)) 
                        AS TglGiling, 
                            (CONVERT(varchar,c.tgltarra,103)+' '+ convert(varchar,c.tgltarra,108)) 
                        AS TglTara, 
                        case when tgltarra is not null then
                        ISNULL(c.bruto, 0)  - ISNULL(c.Tara, 0) + 0.001
                        else  ISNULL(c.bruto, 0) end
                         AS Netto, 
                            isnull(d.RF,'') 
                        as RF, isnull(d.pot,0) 
                        as Potongan
                        FROM         tblSPA a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              vtblpos4 d ON a.spa = d.NoSPA LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              tblbruto c ON a.spa = c.nospa LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              tblgawang b ON a.spa = b.nospa
                        where a.tglberlaku>='2017-08-07 00:00:00' and a.tglberlaku<='2017-08-07 23:59:59'
                        and left(kdptn,5)='IA045'
                        order by a.spa desc";

            // var_dump($query);

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            // $hasil = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $jsonResult = '{"data" :  ';
            $i = 0;
            while ($data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               if($i != 0){
                   $jsonResult .=',';
               }
               $jsonResult .=json_encode($data);
               $i++;
            }
            $jsonResult .= '}';
            // var_dump($jsonResult);
            echo $jsonResult;

?>
```

How i can round the number from JSON?

Comment: please provide result you wanted....

Answer (score 1):

In php:

```
$rounded = round($number, 4);
// Or
$rounded = number_format($number, 4);
```

In javascript:

```
var rounded = number.toFixed(4);
```

Replace 4 with your desired decimal positions

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the native PHP [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.number-format.php) method when outputting data or you can write a Javascript function which rounds or formats numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `number_format('your number',2);` in PHP
.Please try below code demo I have done for your JSON in PHP.

[Number format demo on your provided JSON](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9cb625510ce4720632ac963bccaae0c81910b07b)